# ArrayAdapter getView() position only at 0

Tags: android, listview

Sorry if this seems silly, I just cannot understand this runtime error I'm getting. For reference, here is my code:

[MainActivity.java](http://pastebin.com/ukNX66FW)

[MainListViewRecordAdapter.java](http://pastebin.com/pzLH9W7e)

Currently, I'm getting a NullPointerException on line 27 of the MainListViewRecordAdapter. When I run the debugger, the int position has always been 0, which leads the code to not grad an item out of the ArrayList, causing the NullPointerException. The only thing is, I don't understand why that's happening, why is position always having the value 0?

Comment: Instead of ArrayAdapter use BaseAdapter,through this you do not have to declare position in getView().It will be in its parameters.

Comment: Right, so the link to MainListViewRecordAdapter.java seem to be updated with the answer below, and thats no good for others who are trying to get what happened here... =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you havent initialized Arraylist items and remove line position=1;. do as follows:

```
package com.chigstuff.fun;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainListViewRecordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MainListViewRecord> {
    private ArrayList<MainListViewRecord> items;

    public MainListViewRecordAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<MainListViewRecord> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
this.items=items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.main_list_view_record, null);
        }
        MainListViewRecord item = items.get(position);
        if (item != null) {
            TextView main_list_view_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.main_list_view_text);

            if (main_list_view_text != null) {
                main_list_view_text.setText("What text");
            }
        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: actually if you are using the constructor of the inherited ArrayAdapter, then you can get the item simply with getItem(). the variable items is not needed at all.

Comment: but you are not calling getItem, are you? you are getting item, from items arraylist.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I dont see what the resolution is really.

Comment: I actually found something that worked for me:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15875552/arrayadapter-only-returning-one-position-android/15875581#comment30483550_15875581