# arrayAdapter only returning one position, Android

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I set the arrayList to 12 items, however the arrayAdapter only returns one item on the screen, why is this?   It is supposed to show 12 items on the list.

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ArrayList<CheckBoxInfo> cfo = new ArrayList<CheckBoxInfo>();
CheckBoxInfo cbr;
private ListAdapter MyAdapter;
ListView listview;
MyAdapter myAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    cbr = new CheckBoxInfo();
    cbr.checkBoxName = "dfdjklfjdkljf";
    cbr.checkBoxState = true;

      for(int i = 0; i <12; i++){
            cfo.add(cbr);
      }

      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "size: " + cfo.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(cfo, this);
    listview.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}

public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CheckBoxInfo> {

    private List<CheckBoxInfo> checkBoxList;
    private Context context;

    public MyAdapter(List<CheckBoxInfo> infoList, Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_layout, infoList);
        this.checkBoxList = infoList;
        this.context = context;

    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // First let's verify the convertView is not null
        if (convertView == null) {
            // This a new view we inflate the new layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
        }
            // Now we can fill the layout with the right values
            TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            CheckBoxInfo cbi = checkBoxList.get(position);

              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            tv.setText(cbi.checkBoxName);

        return convertView;
    }

}  // end MyAdapter
  }
```

row_layout.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=" " />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

found out that the problem was the ListView was inside a ScrollView in the xml Layout,  once i removed the outer ScrollView all the items of the ListView showed up.

for some reason if you encapsulate a ListView nested in several layers it will show only one position item if the ListView in inside a ScrollView

Comment: The current documentation (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) says:

"You should never use a ScrollView with a ListView, because ListView takes care of its own vertical scrolling. Most importantly, doing this defeats all of the important optimizations in ListView for dealing with large lists, since it effectively forces the ListView to display its entire list of items to fill up the infinite container supplied by ScrollView."

Comment: What a silly, silly framework. Shame on it. Time lost : 3 hours.

Comment: @Kevik You are god sent for me. I was baffled by why this wont work. and after reading your answer, i removed the scroll view and voila!!!

Comment: Even the outermost scrollview affects any listview, what the freak! Does this have any work around?

Comment: I guess the work around is to create your own custom list view like layout.

Comment: You need to set `android:fillViewport="true"` on `ScrollView` which have `ListView`.

Answer (score 2):

Override `getCount` in your `MyAdapter`

```
public int getCount() {
   return infoList == null ? 0 : infoList.size();
}
```

Comment: Is this really meant to be like that? Why on earth would I be forced to implement the getCount myself? I have passed the arrayList in the super(...)??
Furthermore, I have another project for Android, that I developed like 1 year ago... And then there is no need for that override...

Comment: ... also, overriding that method doesnt change a thing for me.

Answer (score 1):

Please show code of `row_layout`, I think your error is `for` loop:

Try create 2 checkboxs and add manual to test:

```
cbr1 = new CheckBoxInfo();
cbr1.checkBoxName = "checkbox1";
cbr1.checkBoxState = true;
cfo.add(cbr1);

cbr2 = new CheckBoxInfo();
cbr2.checkBoxName = "checkbox2";
cbr2.checkBoxState = true;
cfo.add(cbr2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because my `notifyDataSetChanged()` was inside a loop and wasn't being called in certain circumstances (if there were no data items).

Make sure `notifyDataSetChanged()` is getting called when it should be!

Answer (score 1):

android:fillViewport="true" on ScrollView will solve the problem.