# SetAdapter only works on the first element of String[]

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I am very new to android programming and have been stuck at a problem for a week. There are many similar threads out there who have accomplished what I'm trying to do, but they're not exactly what i want. Or at least I'm unable to understand what they're saying.

I've got a file which is a list of groceries, one on each line. the format is:

```
true  grocery name
true  Another Grocery
false third grocery
```

I am reading this file in my main activity and have built its XML with a fixed Header and Footer and a scrollable dynamic middle layer in another XML which is a `listview` with a `checkbox` inside of it. I have built (actually, Google'd) an Adapter to read the file in a array of Strings and then further apply the first word (true/ false) to the `checkbox` and the rest of the line to the checkbox text. Unfortunately this is only working for the first item in the list.

This was initially working when i dint have a header and my main class was extending ListActivity. But since i wanted more buttons, i changed it to Action Bar and since then I'm unable to use `SetListAdapter`, and forced to use `SetAdapter` instead. Can someone tell me why it only acts upon first line and not all.

**I have a hunch that SetAdapter instead of SetListAdapter might be messing it up.** But I'm not sure. Please let me know if you also need to see my XML structure.

My code is as Follows:

```
   File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
   File groceryList = new File(sdcard, "grocery.txt" );

    // Method to read Data from file
    private void readFile() {

        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(groceryList));
        String line;
        ArrayList<String> item = new ArrayList<String>();

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            item.add(line);
        }
        String[] values = item.toArray(new String[item.size()]);

        br.close();

        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.container);
        list.setAdapter(new GroceryListAdapter(this,values));

        //list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.checkbox, 

    R.id.label, values));
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            ToastMsg("Read Failed!! " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

This is my Adapter:

```
package in.hardikar.apps.grocerylist;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GroceryListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] values;

    public GroceryListAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.checkbox, values);
        this.context = context;
        //Confirmed that the entire file is loading in String[] Values
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.checkbox, parent, false);
        // Inflate the content into the container
        //TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        //ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.logo);

        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        Toast.makeText(context, values[position] + " Loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //textView.setText(values[position]);
        String line = values[position];
        String data[] = line.split(" ",2);

        checkBox.setText(data[1]);
        if(data[0].equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
            checkBox.setChecked(true);
        }
        else {
            checkBox.setChecked(false);
        }
        //inflater.inflate(R.layout.checkbox, list);
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not do this: `list.setAdapter(new GroceryListAdapter(this,values));`. You need to have a reference to `GroceryListAdapter` in order to update your `ListView` when you have new data. **It will only work once**.

Comment: Thanks, i did think that it was wrong syntax, but i'm not sure what is the right way to do it. Back when i was extending ListActivity instead of Action bar, i was able to do this `setListAdapter(new GroceryListAdapter(this, MOBILE_OS));`

Comment: I would not ever use `ListFragment` or `ListActivity`. You `MainActivity` should extend `AppCompatActvity`, then add a `ListView` to your view.

Comment: Keep a reference to your adapter like this:
`GroceryListAdapter groceryListAdapter = new GroceryListAdapter(this, values)`.

Comment: I am afraid i still have the same result. I have the following lines now and now extend AppCompatActivity

`ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.container);
GroceryListAdapter groceryListAdapter = new GroceryListAdapter(this, values);
 list.setAdapter(groceryListAdapter);`

Comment: All I did was provide you with a reference, that shows the initial values. You can use it to update the values you later. You need to debug why it is not all be read in the list. Why are you reading from a text file?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15875552/arrayadapter-only-returning-one-position-android?rq=1)

You cant have list view inside of a scroll view. ListView can take care of scrolling by itself.. wohooo

The [current documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) says: "You should never use a ScrollView with a ListView, because ListView takes care of its own vertical scrolling. Most importantly, doing this defeats all of the important optimizations in ListView for dealing with large lists, since it effectively forces the ListView to display its entire list of items to fill up the infinite container supplied by ScrollView."